Why isn't my PEM certificate file being included in my Axios request?
I have to include a certificate when requesting an API endpoint in Typescript, but I think there is something wrong with my code and that the certificate is not being sent.
I have tried the same details and PEM file in Python and it works fine, but I cannot use Python due to company constraints.
I keep getting a 403 back on the code below and I know this is related to the certificate not being included because if I remove the certificate in the Python program I get a 403 as well.
I cannot see what is wrong so have turned to the community for help.
const axiosConfig = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://someapi.com/api/v1/authorizations/authorize',
        auth: {
          username: 'test@test.com',
          password: 'mypassword'
        },
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
          cert: fs.readFileSync('/Users/myuser/Documents/Dev/cert.pem', 'utf-8'),
        }),
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'CustomAgent',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }

      }
      const response = await axios.request(axiosConfig)


Probably you have the cert and privatekey in one file (in PEM format). python ssl.SSLContext accepts that, and thus so do things that build on it like urllib2 and requests. nodejs tls.createSecureContext does not; it requires either (1) cert: and key: as separate fields (which can each contain the combined PEM content) or else (2) pfx: which includes both cert and key data in a different format not PEM.

@dave_thompson_085 That's perfect and did the trick, thanks
